# Probability that a random graph is an expander

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

I have a random graph $G = (V, E)$ and each edge is in the graph with probability $p$.

I need to show that the probability that $G$ is $\delta$-edge-expander* when $\delta= \frac{np}{4}$ goes to $1$ as $n=|V|\to\infty$.

*A graph is *$\delta$-edge-expander* if for every set of nodes $S$ of size at most $\frac{n}{2}$ it holds that the number of edges from $S$ to $S'$ (where $S'$ is all the nodes that don't appear in $S$) is at least $\delta$.  You can see the definition in this [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph).

Comment: please elaborate on what is a  δ−edge−expander

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by the event that $G$ is "$\delta--edge--expander$. And you should mention that $n$ is the number of vertices of the graph $G$, if that's what $n$ is here.

Comment: The definition on the wiki page requires the edge boundary to be at least $\mathrm{const}\,|S|$, and you wrote "at least $\delta$", without $|S|$.